# Using CodeIgniter Profiler

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm struggling to enable the profiler in CodeIgniter.  I've added it to the `$libraries` config array so it should be auto loaded.  But I'm getting the error...

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function enable_profiler() on a non-object in C:\......\application\core\publiccontroller.php on line 6
```

My code is:

```
<?php
class PublicController extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct () {
        // enable profiler for development
        if (ENVIRONMENT == 'development') {
            $this->output->enable_profiler(true);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

`autoload.php` has....

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Libraries
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| These are the classes located in the system/libraries folder
| or in your application/libraries folder.
|
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'xmlrpc');
*/

$autoload['libraries'] = array('profiler');
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm using CI version 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a note: this suggestion resolves similar issues in CI 1.x, it is not tested in CI 2.
The problem, I suspect is that you're calling that in the constructor before the object has fully initiated itself. Can you confirm $this->load exists? What happens if you put `parent::__construct();` as the first line of the constructor?

Comment: This is exactly right, need to construct the parent class CI_Controller before calling its methods. @Webnet, you don't need to load the profiler: it is not a library, it is part of the Output class which is always loaded.

Comment: @Webnet The reason I knew about that is because I've had more than my share of *headdesks* with the same problem working in CI models.